# Postgres performs seq scan when using with Order By

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

```
select
    thread.id,
    thread.last_modified,
    count(*) as count
from
    thread 
inner join
    comment 
        on thread.id=comment.thread_id 
group by
    thread.id 
    limit 20
```

This query will use index scan as intended[image]

But now if I add `order by` into the query:

```
select
    thread.id,
    thread.last_modified,
    count(*) as count
from
    thread 
inner join
    comment 
        on thread.id=comment.thread_id 
group by
    thread.id 
order by thread.last_modified
    limit 20
```

Postgres will perform 2 seq scan on both `comment` and `thread` like this:
[image]

Even though I have an index on `lastModified`:

```
select thread.id
from thread
order by last_modified
limit 10
```

[image]

So what's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query only has to find the comments to the first 20 threads, while the second one has to select the comments for *all* threads. A sequential scan is the most efficient way to do that.

You can improve the query if you put the `LIMIT` into a subselect in the `FROM` clause:

```
... FROM (SELECT id, last_modified
         FROM thread
         ORDER BY last_modified LIMIT 20) thread
```